# Не работает сайт в IE 11 а в других браузерах работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, internet-explorer

Вот сайт [allbc](http://allbcsite.myjino.ru)

JavaScript работает во всех браузерах кроме Internet Explorer 11. В Edge тоже работает. Как можно исправить эту ошибку? Нужно чтобы работало во всех браузерах.

Comment: Там была проблема с библиотекой D3. Вот ссылка на этот пост [D3 не работает в internet Explorer 11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/967500/d3-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-internet-explorer-11)