# D3 не работает в internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Вот подключение D3 версии 5.7

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/select2.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/charts.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16">
    <title>Allbc</title>
</head>
```

Вот файл charts.js

```
window.onload = function() {

  function chart(data){

    let arc = d3.arc().cornerRadius(10).startAngle(0);
    let svg = d3.select('.chart');
    let size = Math.PI*3/2;
    arcs(true);
    arcs(false);
    svg.selectAll('text').data(data).enter().append('text')
       .text( d => d.text)
       .style('font-size', 10)
       .style('text-anchor', 'end')
       .style('font-family', 'arial')
       .attr('x', -10)
       .attr('y', d => d.index*14-65)

    function arcs(isBg) {
      let selection = svg.selectAll('path.'+ (isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc'))
      selection = selection.data(data).enter().append('path').merge(selection);
      selection.classed(isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc', true)
        .attr('fill', d => isBg ? '#ccc' : d.color)
        .attr('d', d => arc({
          innerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + (d.index?0:3),
          outerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + 8,
          endAngle: isBg ? size : d.value*size/100
        }))
    }

  }

  chart([ 
    [20, '#0578e9', "142 000 м²"], 
    [40, '#f278bb', "82 000 м²"], 
    [60, '#f9b349', "60 000 м²"], 
    [80, '#3eb060', "20 000 м²"]
  ].map((d, i) => ({
    index: i, 
    color: d[1],
    value: d[0],
    text: d[2]
  })));

}
```

График не отображается в Intenet Explorer 11, а в остальных браузерах он работает. Как заставить его работать в Internet Explorer 11 тоже?

Comment: Как минимум, попробуйте стили подключить в head, а не после всего html

Comment: Исправить эту ошибку можно разрабатывая кроссбраузерно. И JS писать кроссбраузерный, и CSS писать кроссбраузерный. Использовать префиксы. Смотреть в https://caniuse.com/ и думать, что можно, а чего нельзя.

Comment: в ie 11 нет поддержки стрелочных функций

Comment: @Qwertiy, в смысле??

Comment: @humster_spb, потому что при условии, что в других браузерах код и так работает, перенос скриптов в head сломать что-то может, а починить - нет. А при том, что подключать скрипты в head - вообще плохой стиль, этот совет совершенно бессмысленный и вредный.

Comment: Вообще-то тебе уже ответили.

Comment: Переместил стили вверх все равно не работает

Comment: Новый head исправил вверху

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправлено из IE, как и сказали в комментариях необходимо и достаточно убрать стрелочные функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function chart(data) {
  let arc = d3.arc().cornerRadius(10).startAngle(0);
  let svg = d3.select('.chart');
  let size = Math.PI*3/2;
  arcs(true);
  arcs(false);
  svg.selectAll('text').data(data).enter().append('text')
     .text( function(d) {
        return d.text;
     })
     .style('font-size', 10)
     .style('text-anchor', 'end')
     .style('font-family', 'arial')
     .attr('x', -10)
     .attr('y', function(d){
      return d.index*14-65;
     })

  function arcs(isBg) {
    let selection = svg.selectAll('path.'+ (isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc'))
    selection = selection.data(data).enter().append('path').merge(selection);
    selection.classed(isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc', true)
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return isBg ? '#ccc' : d.color;
      })
      .attr('d', function(d){
        return arc({
          innerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + (d.index?0:3),
          outerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + 8,
          endAngle: isBg ? size : d.value*size/100
        });
      });
  }

}

chart([ 
  [20, '#0578e9', "142 000 м²"], 
  [40, '#f278bb', "82 000 м²"], 
  [60, '#f9b349', "60 000 м²"], 
  [80, '#3eb060', "20 000 м²"]
].map(function (d, i) {
  return {
    index: i, 
    color: d[1],
    value: d[0],
    text: d[2]
  }
}));
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
 <svg class="chart" viewbox="-100 -100 200 200"></svg>
```

Comment: @Denis пожалуйста, если это прям боевое решение то объем d3 можно сильно порезать, она модульная